# Call to event between UserControls is very slow

Tags: c#

In this example I have got a MainPage and two UserControls

```
MainPage - Page
Content - UC
ButtonPanel - UC
```

In my ButtonPanel I've got a button that deletes an item from the database and after that I wish to update `Content` to diplay the updated content.
To do this I using the following code:

MainPage Xaml:

```
<UC:Content x:Name="Content" />
<Panels:ButtonPanel x:Name="ButtonPanel" />
```

MainPage Codebehind:

```
ButtonPanel.DeleteItem += new EventHandler(UpdateContent);

private void UpdateContent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If i start a stopwatch here and stop it in Content.Refresh()
    // It shows that it took 3000 miliseconds to go from this method
    // Into the Content.Refresh method, without executing any code.
    Content.Refresh();
    OnPropertyChanged("Content");
}
```

Content UC Codebehind:

```
public void Refresh()
{
    // Update content
    // StopWatch shows that running all of this code takes 20 miliseconds.
}
```

ButtonPanel UC Codebehind:

```
private static EventHandler _deleteItem;
public static event EventHandler DeleteItem
{
    add
    {
        if (_deleteItem == null)
        {
            _deleteItem += value;
        }
    }
    remove
    {
        _deleteItem -= value;
    }
}

private void ButtonDelete_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // This takes no time at all either.
    // Delete items from database
    if (_buttonRefreshEvent != null)
        _buttonRefreshEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Basicly what the stopwatches tell me is that it takes 3000 miliseconds to go from my `MainPage` into the `Content.Refresh()`. Why is that and is there anything I can do to reduce this loadspeed, because it is very frustrating.

Comment: There isn't enough here to reproduce the problem. The problem as you describe it isn't very plausible given the code we're looking at, so it would be impossible to give an answer..

Comment: There isn't much more to it to be honest. The Content Usercontrol runs it's own code smoothly. But when the Refresh is called from the MainPage it takes ages to go to the Usercontrol. I've tried moving the code from the Content UserControl to my Mainpage and now it's much smoother. But this isn't really a suitable solution for me.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the operation on the database that's the bottleneck of your solution?

Comment: Yes PiotrWolkowsi, I've run the Refresh method isolated on the Content's UC itself and it's running smoothly.. The problem only occurs when I'm calling .Refresh() from the MainPage